# Iterator pattern return infinite objects

Tags: python

Hello I am trying to build a class list based like this

```
class DummyList(Iterator):
    ...
    def __next__(self) -> int:
        list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        for i in list:
            yield i
```

And I am using like this

```
dl = DummyList()

for i in dl:
    print(i)
```

The output that I expected was

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

But instead I get

```
12345
12345
12345
....
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: You are not constructing an object with that code, you're simply assigning the class DummyList to dl.

Comment: you might want to post your actual code, but anyways, you want `__iter__` here, not `__next__`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would be the correct way to implement an iterator:

```
from collections.abc import Iterator


class DummyList(Iterator):
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
        self.current = -1

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        self.current += 1
        if self.current < len(self.lst):
            return self.lst[self.current]
        raise StopIteration
```

This is the output:

```
dl = DummyList()

for i in dl:
    print(i)
```

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Why is it necessary to subclass Iterator?

Comment: Why not just use OPs original code inside `__iter__` instead of `__next__` like it was suggested in the comments?